# Hindi Font - python 2.7 urllib2 and json

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

```
>>> url = https://graph.facebook.com/508246595873195/posts?limit=1&access_token="token"
>>> import json
>>> import urllib2
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(utl)
>>> data = json.load(response)
>>> for i in data['data'][0]['likes']['data']:
        print i
```

this code scrap likes from post of http://facebook.com (page=Unilever)

{likes} data is like below:

```
{u'id': u'1678630835690215', u'name': u'Binay Barman'}
{u'id': u'770653513044206', u'name': u'\u0926\u0947\u0935 \u092a\u093e\u0930\u0940\u0915'}
```

this `u'\u0926\u0947\u0935 \u092a\u093e\u0930\u0940\u0915'` in normal hindi text it is "देव पारीक"

I want to know how to print this in hindi and not in unicode!!!

Comment: `text.encode('utf-8')` - encode to utf-8 or whatever you use.

Comment: Ah! let the print engine do the work `print u'\u0926\u0947\u0935 \u092a\u093e\u0930\u0940\u0915'.encode('utf_8_sig')`

Comment: @SIslam, this results = ï»¿à¤¦à¥‡à¤µ à¤ªà¤¾à¤°à¥€à¤•

Answer (score -1):

for Example:

```
>>> a = u'\u0926\u0947\u0935 \u092a\u093e\u0930\u0940\u0915'
>>> a.encode('utf-8')
```

result:

```
'\xe0\xa4\xa6\xe0\xa5\x87\xe0\xa4\xb5\xe0\xa4\xaa\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa5\x80\xe0\xa4\x95'
```

I want this in hindi font

Comment: try `print( a.encode('utf-8') )` - if you don't use `print` then console use `repr()` to print it -  `print( repr( a.encode('utf-8') ) )`

Comment: @furas result of print( repr( a.encode('utf-8') ) ) is 

'\xe0\xa4\xa6\xe0\xa5\x87\xe0\xa4\xb5 \xe0\xa4\xaa\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa5\x80\xe0\xa4\x95'

Comment: and result of `print(a.encode('utf-8'))` (without `repr`) ?  `repr()` is used by console/shell when you don't use `print()` directly.

Comment: @furas, result is à¤¦à¥‡à¤µ à¤ªà¤¾à¤°à¥€à¤•